# Gridmanager jQuery - addRow()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the gridmanager.js plugin and i'm trying to add rows from an external button. I'm following the examples from documentation but i can't get it working.

The code i'm using is this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var gm = jQuery("#mycanvas").gridmanager({
                debug: 1
            }).data('gridmanager');

            $(".myexternalcontrol").on("click", function(e){
                gm.createRow();

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: One of your major issues is the "jQuery" sitting in there.
var gm = $("#mycanvas").gridmanager({debug: 1}).data('gridmanager');

Comment: Solved, Thank you!